# How to Parse an integer out of an expect test mySQL response?

Tags: expect

Does anyone know how i can parse the integer out of the following console output within an expect test?

```
  +-----------------+
  | static_route_id |
  +-----------------+
  |             314 |
  +-----------------+
```

What i would like to do is

```
    proc testRouteId { identity_regex } {

          #sign into database (got it)

          #fetch routes with matching identity_regex (a column in the database)
          send { select static_route_id from static_routes where identity_regex="$identity_regex"; }
          send "\r"

          #parse the routeId out of the console output somehow
          expect {
            timeout { send_user "fetchStaticRouteId timed out\n"; return 0 }
            eof { send_user "fetchStaticRouteId failed\n"; return 0 }

          =========Stuck on the regex =========
            -re "REGEX?" { send_user "fetchStaticRouteId $expect_out(1, string)\n" }
          }
          return routeId; # (an int)
        }
```

Comment: Why minus one? This is a reasonable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution

```
  proc itemId { databaseName idRegex } {
      set query = "select itemId from tableName where idRegex = '$idRegex';"
      spawn -noecho mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD $databaseName -B -e "$query"
      expect {
        timeout {send_user "itemId timed out"; return 0 }
        eof {send_user "itemId failed"; return 0}
        "routeId" {
          expect {
            -re { *(\d+).*} { set itemId $expect_out(1,string) }
          }
        } 
      }
      return $itemId
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `expect` command to match a regex pattern, capture the sequence of digits surrounded by pipes and whitespace, and extract the digits from the `expect_out` array.

Here, I'm using the Tcl `format` command (like sprintf) to make the send string easier to work with. You send command will *not* expance the variable because you use braces -- see https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm rule number 6.

```
send [format {select static_route_id from static_routes where identity_regex="%s";\r} $identity_regex]
expect -re {\|\s+(\d+)\s+\|.*}
return $expect_out(1,string)
```

Comment: Glenn, i edited the question to make it a bit clearer. What you wrote above didn't work for me.

Comment: The variable is `expect_out(1,string)` without a space -- Tcl arrays are *associative* arrays, not multidimensional indexed arrays: the array key  `1, string` is different from `1,string`

Comment: Did you understand what I'm saying about the `$identity_regex` not expanding inside of braces?